# Crawler results missing

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

I'm new to crawler and I started with python and requests + beautifulsoup.
I follow the instructions I found online and the code looks like this
the destinating website is https://acgn-stock.com/

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://acgn-stock.com/", headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

It's really basic and I understand everything in it.
when I execute it, it did work but something is missing.
The web's code looks like this
[image]

but my crawler only crawled thing above this line

```
<script>window.prerenderReady = false</scrip>
```

I've tried to change the user-agent but it still didn't work.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems that those elements are added by javascript. Aren't they?

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add elements then `requests` adn `BS` can be useless because they can't run JavaScript. You may use `Selenium` to control web browser which can run JavaScript. Eventually you can check in `DevTool` in `Firefox`/`Chrome` if JavaScript read data from server and use this url with `requests`/`BS` (or often with `json`) to get data.